# than (what/those)

Tags: comparative-constructions

> 1. This is a more carefully researched article than I have read this semester.

2. This is a more carefully researched article than **what** I have read this semester.
3. This is a more carefully researched article than **those** I have read this semester.

The first sentence is from my textbook.  I want to know if I can  insert "what" or "those", as in (2) and (3) respectively.  If all of them work, which one(s) is commonly used？

Comment: Idiomatically speaking, I'd much prefer ***any*** rather than ***what, those, [nothing]***. I can't see any justification for using Present Perfect rather than Simple Past anyway, but I have to say that - regardless of whether it's formally "grammatical" or not - *[A better article] **than what I read last term*** sounds a bit "downmarket, slangy" to me, whereas ***...than any I read last term*** sounds much more "upmarket, formal, literary".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three sentences are grammatically valid. By using the plural "those", #3 clearly says that you have read more than one article, while #1 and #2 don't specify whether it is one or many. That's the only difference.

#1 is an example of "elision", leaving out words whose meaning is implied. It should be obvious from context that the intent is, "This is a more carefully research article than THE ARTICLES I have read this semester." As in your examples, you could say "what" or "those" instead of "the articles".

All three forms are commonly used. I'd guess #1 is somewhat more common but all would be readily understood.

Comment: Thank you, Jay.